# How do I completely disable HTML5 Video playback on Safari?

Tags: safari, video, google-chrome, safari-extensions

I am so sick & tired of HTML5 videos, that I just want to completely disable them. I don't want em playing at all. Even if I click on them or whatever.

I found [this extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-content-blocker/nobnkgabkebhhlgfddbemmefjnjnahoe/related?hl=en), which does the trick. Looking for something like this on Safari

PS: I did try converting this extension, but the resulting extension while appearing to work, is unable to actually block videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My prev attempt at fixing this with AdGuard failed miserably. However, I just found an option in-built in Safari that solves my problem.

My initial frustrations were relating to HTML5 videos, mainly relating to the fact that they continue to auto-play even when Safari was set to not let them. And so I figured let's just disable them altogether. But maybe that was too extreme of an option. This one is a lot better!

The solution

1. Enable Safari Debug Menu

Run this in a Terminal window. To disable the menu replace the `1` with a `0`

`defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1`

2. Restart Safari
3. Open the Debug Menu, and head over to `Media Flags`
4. Enable the `Video Needs User Action` & `Audio Needs User Action`
5. Restart Safari
6. Now laugh at the puny websites trying their futile attempts to auto-play videos **BWAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA**

PS: If you are a reddit user, you might just wanna head over to their website and just try it out with these options enabled

Tested on Safari Version 14.0.2 (16610.3.7.1.9)

Comment: This now only works if Terminal has Full Disk Access. See https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/containers.html Even still, this answer doesn't go far enough. Clicking on a web link can still be hijacked and used to start video against the user's will. For example, on yahoo.com/news, if you even open a URL to a story with a video—even in a new tab—from then on, all videos will autoplay on the main page, as you scroll them into view.

Comment: Safari is not worth it. I switched to FireFox